# Fitting a table in the page with no column names broken by hyphenation

Tags: tables, fit

I´m trying to fit a table in the page so it has text width and looks fine. In  fact, the code below fits the table, but it breaks column names (e.g. "Ditado" becomes "Di-tado"). It´s possible to do that?
Thanks!

Saulo.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{\label{tab:jogos-aval-diag} Habilidades verificadas na avaliação diagnóstica exercitada por cada jogo}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{|L|C|C|C|C|} 
\hline 
\hline \textbf{Habilidade}  & \textbf{Forma palavras} & \textbf{Ditado}&      \textbf{Brincando com as vogais} & \textbf{A procura das cartas}\\
\hline 
\hline Identificar letras do alfabeto. &    X   & X &X  &X\\ 
\hline Diferenciar letras de outros sinais gráficos como os números, desenhos, rabiscos, símbolos gráficos (asteriscos, sinais matemáticos, sinais de trânsito, etc.). &    & X & & \\
\hline Distinguir diferentes tipos de letras. & & & & \\
\hline Compreender a função de segmentação de espaços em branco na delimitação de palavras em textos escritos. & X &X &X &X \\
\hline Reconhecer unidades fonológicas como as sílabas, rimas, terminações de palavras.& & & &X\\
\hline Compreender a natureza alfabética do sistema de escrita.& X &X &X &X \\
\hline Saber decodificar palavras. & X &X &X &X \\
\hline Saber ler reconhecendo globalmente as palavras. & X &X & &X  \\
\hline Saber decodificar pequenos textos escritos. & X &X &X &X \\
\hline Escrever frases. &   & & & \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\captionfont{\small{\textbf{\\Fonte: }}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) probably the easiest way to prevent a word in the table heading from being broken is to pack it into an `\mbox{...}`.  but that will increase the width of those columns, so use `\mbox` on each breakable word individually, to keep the expansion to a minimum.

Comment: Have you tried writing `\mbox{Ditado}`?

Comment: Thanks Barbara! But it doesn´t work and the word gets out of column limits. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions, using the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks and a common formatting of column heads. One uses `tabulary` as in your post, the other `tabularx`, in order to have the last four columns with equal widths. Il also improved vertical spacing with the `cellspace` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\footnotesize}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{cc}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X, J}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H] \tymax=1\linewidth
\caption{\label{tab:jogos-aval-diag} Habilidades verificadas na avaliação diagnóstica exercitada por cada jogo}
\footnotesize\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{|S{J}|c|c|c|c|}
\Xhline{0.8pt}\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\thead{Habilidade} & \thead{Forma\\palavras} & \thead{Ditado}& \thead{Brincando\\com as\\ vogais} & \thead{A procura\\ das cartas}\\
\hline\noalign{smallskip}\hline
 Identificar letras do alfabeto. & X & X &X &X\\
\hline
Diferenciar letras de outros sinais gráficos como os números, desenhos, rabiscos, símbolos gráficos (asteriscos, sinais matemáticos, sinais de trânsito, etc.). & & X & & \\
\hline
Distinguir diferentes tipos de letras. & & & & \\
\hline
Compreender a função de segmentação de espaços em branco na delimitação de palavras em textos escritos. & X &X &X &X \\
\hline
Reconhecer unidades fonológicas como as sílabas, rimas, terminações de palavras.& & & &X\\
\hline
Compreender a natureza alfabética do sistema de escrita.& X &X &X &X \\
\hline
Saber decodificar palavras. & X &X &X &X \\
\hline
Saber ler reconhecendo globalmente as palavras. & X &X & &X \\
\hline
Saber decodificar pequenos textos escritos. & X &X &X &X \\
\hline
Escrever frases. & & & & \\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\Xhline{0.8pt}
\end{tabulary}\medskip
\captionfont{\small{\textbf{\\Fonte: }}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H] \tymax=1\linewidth
\caption{\label{tab:jogos-aval-diag} Habilidades verificadas na avaliação diagnóstica exercitada por cada jogo}
\footnotesize\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=2.5\hsize}S{X}|*{4}{S{>{\hsize=0.625\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}|}}
\Xhline{0.8pt}\noalign{\smallskip}
\hline
\thead{Habilidade} & \thead{Forma\\palavras} & \thead{Ditado}& \thead{Brincando\\com as\\ vogais} & \thead{A procura\\ das cartas}\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
 Identificar letras do alfabeto. & X & X &X &X\\
\hline
Diferenciar letras de outros sinais gráficos como os números, desenhos, rabiscos, símbolos gráficos (asteriscos, sinais matemáticos, sinais de trânsito, etc.). & & X & & \\
\hline
Distinguir diferentes tipos de letras. & & & & \\
\hline
Compreender a função de segmentação de espaços em branco na delimitação de palavras em textos escritos. & X &X &X &X \\
\hline
Reconhecer unidades fonológicas como as sílabas, rimas, terminações de palavras.& & & &X\\
\hline
Compreender a natureza alfabética do sistema de escrita.& X &X &X &X \\
\hline
Saber decodificar palavras. & X &X &X &X \\
\hline
Saber ler reconhecendo globalmente as palavras. & X &X & &X \\
\hline
Saber decodificar pequenos textos escritos. & X &X &X &X \\
\hline
Escrever frases. & & & & \\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\Xhline{0.8pt}
\end{tabularx}\medskip
\captionfont{\small{\textbf{\\Fonte: }}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Bernard! Yes, your solutions really look nice!  I eally thank you. BTW, I don´t know weather I should to start a new quesion, but I´m trying to use your solution in anothher table with one multicolumn (in the first two colummns) and two multirows below it through 3 rows each. In fact these "multi" seems to work, but the table returns to get out of text width/page limits... Could you help once again?

Comment: I'd be glad to, but I must see the concrete problem. It was an answer to which question?